# Load Mapinfo to Mapserver

Tags: mapserver, mapinfo

I am a newbie in mapserver, i was reading tutorial (http://mapserver.org/input/vector/mapinfo.html) but i have a problem load mapinfo into mapserver ( i'm using pmapper). no error anything, but the map cannot show in mapserver. how can i do for this problem?

this is my code in layer:

```
LAYER
NAME INDO_PROP
TYPE POLYGON
STATUS DEFAULT
CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
CONNECTION "INDO_PROP.TAB"
STYLEITEM "AUTO"
CLASS
        NAME "INDO_PROP"
END
PROJECTION
"AUTO"
END
END # Layer
```

i'm sorry to my bad english :)

Thanks,

Sebedjo

Comment: is your tab file in the same folder as the map file?  If you set DEBUG 4 in your map file, do you get any warnings in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

check 1: double check that syntax of you mapfile does not cause problems, this can be done by going to your browser and setting the URL to `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=<absolute path to mapfile: e.g D:\ms4w\mapfiles\mymapfile.map >` .... check out the message it returns in your browser window.

check 2: If no error message appears from "check 1" then make sure the projection is correct, if you overlay maps from different reference systems withouth specifying in the "PROJECTION" tag in your layer the overlay will not be correct and your map might be drawn in a completely different position!